# Why use external compensation on a buck IC?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck

The [AP64200](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP64200.pdf), with block diagram of

[image: block diagram]

says about loop compensation that

> The goal of loop compensation design is to achieve:
>
> - High DC Gain
> - Gain Margin less than -10dB
> - Phase Margin greater than 45°
> - Loop Bandwidth Crossover Frequency (fC) less than 10% of fSW

but the specsheet also says that the COMP pin can simply be grounded. What is the consequence to grounding the COMP pin for the behaviour of the regulator? Said another way, how does the designer balance the space and component costs of adding R5/C5 external compensation passives with the benefit of enabling external compensation, whatever that may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compensation can be used to *optimize* the performance of the DCDC. Following the goals listed (except DC gain), having performance better than the minimum can improve transient response (so saving on the output capacitor), avoid ringing on the output. Just using 'default' compensation may keep the circuit stable, but optimizing and tuning it for the particular component selection used may give better performance.

Answer (score 3):

The tradeoffs in a good step-down regulator are the LP Filter characteristics at both no-load and max load are:

- good attenuation of pulse spectrum  (low breakpoint)
- fast step load response with low lag and low overshoot. (high breakpoint)
- good phase margin at min. to  max. load current or impedance.

Q is the quality factor of sharpness of a filter also amplifies noise with reactive gain from stored energy. So high Q means high inertia from stored energy making it harder to regulate, slower to correct from loading effects yet lower ripple.   So these are critical tradeoffs for overall voltage error. However at full load with low Q the phase shift is now spread over a decade around the breakpoint and that can reduce phase margin in the closed loop.  Therefore voltage phase-lead compensation is important and so is current feedback.

My best estimate for the LC components is to start with the sqrt(L/C)=Zo reactive impedance and get that down towards the minimum Rload. So 3.3V/2A= 1.65 Ohms.  However even more critical for low voltage noise, step error and overshoot is also to have very high Q reactive components  Q>> 100 for a 1% error contribution.

- This means a very high impedance ratio of X(f)/ESR or X(f)/DCR for cap and chokes respectively.  This means it may be easier to choose a higher frequency converter with low milliohm inductors and capacitors.

The low L/C=Zo² only defines the low reactance impedance to nearly match the load R but not the actual values. Since the resonance is defined by  \$ω_0=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{LC}}\$ and ω = 2πf for ripple attenuation requirements, we can also use the time domain and consider how the loop bandwidth is important to maximize for speed of error correction with minimum ringing.

Often the breakpoint is at most 5% of the switching frequency for -46 dB of attenuation of the PWM ripple current.  The load impedance and tradeoffs for component cost and error specs are critical to choosing optimal compensation feedback and current sensing internal to the IC.